# why does grep stop matching and error with binary file matches

Tags: linux, mod-security, grep

**QUESTION**

Why does my grep command match some lines and then stop with this error
grep: /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log: binary file matches

My grep command:
grep '^[' /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log

I'm guessing there is binary content in the log file and that is messing up the grep? But I am guessing, so please explain what the cause is. Also please explain what I can do to get around it.

The log file itself is ASCII text. I can use less to read it
file /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines (9938)

**SETUP**

On my webserver I have modsec installed. The audit file is a multiline record described here
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-2-Data-Formats#user-content-Parts

FYI I am logging these parts
SecAuditLogParts ABCEFHJZ

The A part is the audit log header is only one line, with the following information on it:
Timestamp
Unique transaction ID
Source IP address (IPv4 or IPv6)
Source port
Destination IP address (IPv4 or IPv6)
Destination port

e.g.
[05/Jan/2024:00:45:31.734758 +0000] ZZdRKyjPxuLDuK2XVhEfLgAAAAU 198.12.243.17 13914 192.168.2.143 443

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

I'm trying to grep the A part out of the many, many lines and use it as easy reference of what's happened on any given day and at what time the bot activity was most busy. There's lots of better ways to do this, but please stay on track - what's going wrong with grep and how do I overcome it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` by default does not like to output binary data (as outputting binary data may well mess up the terminal, for instance) and therefore it defaults to just indicating a match saying `binary file matches` for binary files.

If you want the output anyway, you may want the `-a` option.
See the relevant section from the manual for details:

```
   -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.

   --binary-files=TYPE
          If  a  file's  data or metadata indicate that the file contains binary data, assume that the file is of
          type TYPE.  Non-text bytes indicate binary data; these are either  output  bytes  that  are  improperly
          encoded for the current locale, or null input bytes when the -z option is not given.

          By  default, TYPE is binary, and grep suppresses output after null input binary data is discovered, and
          suppresses output lines that contain improperly encoded data.  When some  output  is  suppressed,  grep
          follows any output with a message to standard error saying that a binary file matches.

          If  TYPE  is  without-match, when grep discovers null input binary data it assumes that the rest of the
          file does not match; this is equivalent to the -I option.

          If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the -a option.

          When type is binary, grep may treat non-text bytes as line terminators  even  without  the  -z  option.
          This  means choosing binary versus text can affect whether a pattern matches a file.  For example, when
          type is binary the pattern q$ might match q immediately followed by a null byte, even  though  this  is
          not  matched when type is text.  Conversely, when type is binary the pattern . (period) might not match
          a null byte.

          Warning: The -a option might output binary garbage, which can have nasty side effects if the output  is
          a  terminal  and  if  the  terminal  driver interprets some of it as commands.  On the other hand, when
          reading files whose text encodings are unknown, it can be helpful to use -a or to set LC_ALL='C' in the
          environment, in order to find more matches even if the matches are unsafe for direct display.
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Håkan Lindqvist. I'm trying to mark it as solved/correct. Working out how to